# Any way to save Suricata alert payload?

Tags: snort, graylog

I've followed some directions for setting up Graylog and Snort (I used Suricata however) [here](https://www.graylog.org/post/visualize-and-correlate-ids-alerts-with-open-source-tools) but it would be nice to be able to see what the Alert payload was which generated the event.

An application named [Snorby](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Snorby) used to do this beautifully. You could view a hex dump of the payload to better determine the criticality of an event. As far as I know, development on Snorby ceased quite some time ago. Does anyone know if there's a way to get this sort of functionality with Graylog/Suricata? I guess if Suricata can save the payload somehow, it could be sent to Graylog somehow just not sure what mechanism would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [EveBox](https://github.com/jasonish/evebox) to see the Suricata's alerts, events and so on. It can also show the graph report if you use Elasticsearch.

The EveBox is a web-based Suricata "eve" event viewer for Elastic Search.

**Features:**

- A web-based event viewer with an "Inbox" approach to alert management.
  Event search.
- An agent for sending Suricata events to the EveBox server (but you can use Filebeat/Logstash instead).
- Embedded SQLite for self-contained installations.

[image: Suricata web-based report]